# Problem about LFT carries one pair of concentric circles into another pair of concentric circles

Tags: complex-analysis, linear-transformations

While I tried to prove a problem,

> > Suppose that a linear fractional transformation carries one pair of concentric circles into another pair of concentric circles. Prove that the ratios of the radii must be the same.

Following is my try

> Suppose concentric circles $z_1=\alpha+Re^{i\theta}$ and $z_2=\alpha+t Re^{i\theta}$, where $t>0,\ \theta\in [0,2\pi)$, through LFT $\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ mapping to 
>         $$
>     \omega_1=\frac{a Re^{i\theta}+a\alpha+b}{cRe^{i\theta}+c\alpha +d};\\
>   \omega_2=\frac{a tRe^{i\theta}+a\alpha+b}{ctRe^{i\theta}+c\alpha +d}.
>    $$
>
> According to condition the mapping maps the concentric circles to concentric circles, so $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ are concentric. Suppose $\omega_1=\beta_1+R_1e^{i\theta}$ and $\omega_2=\beta_2+R_2e^{i\theta}$, solve the equations, we get the results as follows,
>         $$
>   \beta_1\to \frac{(a \alpha+b) (\alpha c+d)-a c R^2}{(\alpha  c+d)^2-c^2 R^2},R_1\to \frac{R (a d-b c)}{(\alpha  c+d)^2-c^2 R^2};
>    $$
>         $$
>   \beta_2\to \frac{(a \alpha+b) (\alpha c+d)-a c R^2 t^2}{(\alpha c+d)^2-c^2 R^2 t^2},R_2\to \frac{R t (a d-b c)}{(\alpha c+d)^2-c^2 R^2 t^2}.
>    $$
>           We simplify $\beta_1-\beta_2=0$, that is 
>         $$
>     c(c\alpha+ d)=0.
>    $$
>   (i)$c=0$, $R_2/R_1=t$.
>
> (ii)$c\alpha+d=0$, $R_2/R_1=1/t$.

Now my question is the first situation is normal and second one seems like the original proposition is not right, what's wrong?

Besides, I think my way to solve this question especially solving the equations are complicated, it there any other simpler solution? Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure what your mean by the four right arrows, but I think you can get your answer from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23646/m%C3%B6bius-transformations-and-concentric-circles?rq=1